# Error with google appengine using pyramid

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pyramid

Using pyramid_appengine my project works fine but, when i deploy to GAE i have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 187, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 225, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~muncompy/v3.359898035587494190/muncompy/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    application = make_app()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~muncompy/v3.359898035587494190/muncompy/__init__.py", line 32, in make_app
    config.scan()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~muncompy/v3.359898035587494190/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 912, in scan
    ignore=ignore)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~muncompy/v3.359898035587494190/venusian/__init__.py", line 189, in scan
    __import__(modname)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~muncompy/v3.359898035587494190/muncompy/conftest.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import dev_appserver_index
ImportError: No module named tools
```

Any ideas for why module tools from google.appengine is missing?

Comment: Did you put the files under the same folder where your app.yaml is or deeper?

Comment: Yes, all files from my project and packages included are put in the same project folder (pyramid_appengine's buildout do this) but appengine packages is included automatically (i guest that). Other import from google.appengine.... are work fine.

Comment: As far as I know pyramid is not included in the default package..

Comment: This module "tools" is included with appengine. Running pcreate with -t appengine_startup is created a project with conftest.py for tests. This file has the line with error. I solve this problem (for now) with #